# Crystal report cant navigate to next page C#

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a Crystal report that displays client data according to a period .

Report working fine. However clicking on the report to switch to the next page a message appears: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

[image]

Comment: which line of code is throwing this error , if you are not able to  find the line try commenting try catch and run in debug mode and when error comes it will stop at that line ,,, looks like a coding error, once you get the line of code which is causing this error we can think of how to avoid that

Comment: When clicking next page button in report, code part is not calling. That is report function I think.

Comment: this Crystal Report Forms Viewer... that is generated by you or somebody else?